# magento 2.3 | bin/magento setup:di:compile .. Stops @ 14%

Tags: magento2

i cant run this command "php bin/magento setup:di:compile" it stops @ 14%
i have a magento2 - Dedicated Server and when i run di:compile i seee the below error

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation...
1/7 [====>-----------------------] 14%

once it reach 14% is just stops?

i tried many ways to solve it, cleared the cache and rebuild the deployment but with no use, i even removed the cache manually in var/ and generated/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run the command with some extra parameters, like this:

`php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile`

The compiling could be stopped by exhausted allow memory size. If not, could you please remove the log files in var/log, run the command again and post the outcome of the logs here?

Answer (score 0):

> $php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------] 14%
I will stop running and shows

PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 14256 bytes exhausted

> in php.ini,
>   **memory_limit= -1**

Comment: in my case it was a normal php script error .. there was a flag that i used to debug the command which i cant remember now, but debug it to know exactly which file has the php error

Answer (score 0):

**In Our Case, There was special character get added in PHP file before php tag like Y#tE!t<?php.**

what was wrong with us that we open vendor file through FTP and close it and its get updated with some special character(One reason due to Not used IDE or proper text-editor).